# Face recognition using python and opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I want to work on [this face recognition project](https://github.com/kitsook/face) but when I run the `train.py`, I get the following error:

```
recognizer = cv2.face.createFisherFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'face'
```

I've googled it but I didn't find anything useful.

I'm running `python 2.7` and `OpenCV 3.2.0`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: probably your "import cv2" never imported correctly

Comment: @user1767754 it is installed correctly, but I think this is because of the OpenCV version. I haven't found anything helpful on the web.

Comment: The "face" module is from [opencv_contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/face). Are you sure that the build of OpenCV you're using contains this? AFAIK most of the standard builds don't contain the contrib modules.

Comment: @DanMašek I tried 
`brew install opencv --with-contrib --with-ffmpeg --with-tbb --without-tests --HEAD` 
but it says:
`Warning: homebrew/science/opencv: this formula has no --with-contrib option so it will be ignored!`. 
What should I do now?

Comment: Sorry, don't have any experience with `brew`. Search around a bit, I'd assume you're not the first person trying to do this. Another option might be to just try to build it straight from sources just using CMake.

Comment: @DanMašek Thanks man, your first comment helped a lot. The answer is to use OpenCV3 to work. Something like this: `brew install opencv3 --with-contrib`

Comment: @mohamaddanesh Great. However, instead of editing your title as you have, you should write your own answer to your question (and accept it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DanMašek in the comments said, the answer is to add the open_contrib module in the OpenCV to use face module. It can be done while installing OpenCV, like this:

```
brew install opencv3 --with-contrib
```